# Angular - Include extra ts file in current ts file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, include, export

I'm new to Angular and looking through the documentation but thought I'd also ask my question here.

I'm exporting a class which is getting large so I'd like to break it up into two files and store d1, d2, d3, etc in a separate file and import them where d1 is located below.

```
  export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  name: string;
  AppModule;
  d1: string = " lengthy string of text";
  d2: string = " another lengthy string of text";
  d3: string = " another lengthy string of text";
  // goes on for many lines

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.name = "Home";
  } ...
```

What's the best way to do achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The most simple and angular-unspecific approach for the original question would be to just make a file like string.ts:

```
export const d1 : string = "Hello World, this is a long string.";
```

and import the string via

```
 import {d1} from './string';
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ayepho

Comment: Thanks fortuneNext, once I added `d1:string = d1;` in the export class it worked great.